# C# ByteArray to Image

Tags: c#, image, file, arrays, memorystream

I need to convert a `byte[]` to an `Image`, but I cannot make it work in C#. If I save the `bytearray` to a file like this:

```
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create("test.jpg"))
{
    fs.Write(bytearray, 0, (int)lenght);
    fs.Close();
}
```

And test.jpg shows properly. But when I try to make Image from the bytearray like this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytearray);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

It shows only black box.

Comment: code looks good to me. Can you confirm that the byte array being converted to an image has the same length before it was saved into a file?

Comment: Can you please post all the code you are using to load the image at the PictureBox?

Comment: Im actually making the image from the array before saving to a file.
`code`test`code`

Comment: Basically this is the whole code.. before that Im just converting IntPtr to byte[] which is used there.
`byte[] bytearray = new byte[lenght];
Marshal.Copy(pBuf, bytearray, 0, (int)lenght);`

Answer (score 0):

I guess one problem is since you are creating test.jpg, it doesn't have any data and so the bytearray is empty.

Do something like :-

```
            byte[] fileData = null;
            using (var fs = new FileStream("C:\\1\\roses.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                var totalLength = (int)fs.Length;
                using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fs))
                    {
                    fileData = new byte[totalLength];
                    fs.Read(fileData, 0, totalLength);
                    fs.Close();
                    }
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fileData);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                }
```

Comment: OP says image saves fine, but shows a black box on a form. So i guess there is the data in `bytearray ` already.

Comment: Yea, the image saves fine. The bytearray isnt empty.

Comment: What I have seen is that if I try to read a .png file the data in bytearray is non zero. But if I try to read a .jpg file the file data is all 0, hence the last line in my code throws exception.
Can you verify that you are getting non-zero data in bytearray ?

You may get black box because of zero data. Can you confirm contents of your byte array ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, all was my bad. The code is correct, but the reason why it was showing only black screen was, becuase the picture was so big and it was black in the corners. And the pictureBox was not resizing it or anything so it showed its top right corner only.